# Spoilers in Game of Thrones (2012 Role-Playing Game)

Tags: game-of-thrones

I would like to play Game of Thrones (the 2012 Role-Playing Game), but I am not up to date with the books/TV series.

I have watched seasons 1 & 2, and I have read the first 3 books (A Game of Thrones, A Clash of Kings & A Storm of Swords, parts 1 & 2) and don't want any spoilers to ruin the books for me.

Are there any spoilers within the game events that happen in the books or TV series?

Is there any information that specifies the 'minimum' point that you can play without any spoilers?

I guess what I really want to know is at what point in the novels the game reaches to (without spoilers).

Comment: Whether it ruins it or not is going to be rather subjective, I'm afraid.  There's no objective way to say that it will or won't ruin the story for you.

Comment: I've edited to remove the subjective framing. Personally, I'm a purest, so any spoiler is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Realistically, people play it because they enjoy the GoT world.  If you don't want to get spoiled, the only real choice you have is not to play it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2012 RPG has a story that is largely independent of the *A Song of Ice and Fire* novel series and *Game of Thrones* television show. It shares a fictional universe, and some locations, but the characters and plot are different and the timeline of the game finishes around halfway through the first book.